# SSM runCommand document with conditional branching

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am creating a aws ssm document and in the first step, I am trying to run shell script.

```
- name: checkMembership
  action: 'aws:runCommand'
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
    InstanceIds:
      - '{{InstanceIds}}'
    Parameters:
      commands:
        - mkdir testFolder
```

my question is would I be able to do a multi-line if else here with the powershell script or shell script?

```
- name: checkMembership
  action: 'aws:runCommand'
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
    InstanceIds:
      - '{{InstanceIds}}'
    Parameters:
      commands:
        - if $foo
        - then
        - echo 'hello'
        - else
        - echo 'bye'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use conditional branching in the command.

Here's an example:

```
"runCommand": [
    "#!/bin/bash",
    "example_var=true",
    "   if [ \"$example_var\" = true ] ;",
    "   then",
    "     echo \"example_var is true\"",
    "   else",
    "     echo \"example_var is not true\"",
    "   fi"
]
```

I recommend you take a look at the AWS managed documents. There are some really good examples there that you can reference.